# How can I say that 2 variables are statistically independent from their probability density function??

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm know through my text book ,that these property is valid for statistically independent variable:

[property 1 for waited values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea67F.png)

$$\mathsf E\left[\prod\limits_{i=1}^n g_i(x_i)\right]=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \mathsf E\left[g_i(x_i)\right]$$
[property 2  for probability density function(p.d.f)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsM6p.png)

$$p_{x,y}(X,Y)=p_x(X)\,p_y(Y)$$

but in one question, two p.d.f  from x and y random variables was given to me : [figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leh9f.png)
$$\begin{align}p_x(X)&=ae^{-aX}u(X)\\[1ex]p_y(Y)&=be^{-bY}u(Y)\end{align}$$

If I had the $p_{x,y}(X,Y)$ function, I'd know previously if $x$ and $y$ are statistically independents variables, however I only have $p_x(X)$ and $p_y(Y)$, and I don't know how to conclude hat $x$ and $y$ are statistically independents. I one resolution of my university list, it's assumed, in case of figure 3, that x and y are statistically independents,but I don't know how and why. Could someone give me an idea??

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, no.

By themselves, those two marginal probability density functions are not enough to lay claim to independence.

There would need to be some *other reason* provided in the question for you to be able to justify that assumption.

However, without seeing the whole question, we cannot point to what that reason might be.

Comment: the question gave this  two random variables. X is about a equipment lifetime and Y is the  equipment recovery. And there's a third variable Z= X + Y that model the cycle time. The question only give the meaning of each variable, but don't say nothing beyond that.

Comment: note: the question didn't give pxy(X,Y). it's in portuguese and  I can't translate the question very well.

Comment: So is it reasonable, or not, to assume that equipment life time and equipment recovery time might be independent processes?

Comment: yes, but it's an assumption. I'd be more sure if I could prove that x and y are statistically independent in a mathematically way.